# RCharts multicharts disable MinMax value

Tags: r, nvd3.js, rcharts

I'm using Rcharts multicharts as below and am trying to hide the minmax value on the y axis. I have done this before using p12$yAxis(showMaxMin = FALSE) but the graph does not display anymore if i use it here. I suspect it needs to be in the "set(multi = list(...." format. 
Has anyone figured this out yet?
Any help much appreciated! 
Thanks

```
library(rCharts)
library(ggplot2)
data(economics, package = 'ggplot2')
ecm <- reshape2::melt(economics[,c('date','uempmed','psavert')],id = 'date')
p12<- nPlot(value ~ date, group = 'variable', data = ecm, type = 'multiChart')
p12$setTemplate(script = system.file("/libraries/nvd3/layouts/multiChart.html",package =     "rCharts"))
p12$set(multi = list( uempmed = list(type="area", yAxis=1), psavert = list(type="line", yAxis=2)))
```